# How to avoid post-back of Check Box inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am newbie for asp.net,
I have a repeater which contains check box,whenever I check the check box I am firing an event on checkchanged,but the page postbacks.
I have an update panel for the entire content in my page,but still postback occurs.Is there anyway to avoid postback.
(Ps:To avoid Postback,I am meaning to avoid the flicker that occurs)

Thanks

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptrDepartment" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptrDepartment_ItemCommand"
                            OnItemDataBound="rptrdepartment_databound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                   <td>
                                      <asp:CheckBox ID ="chkRow" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ChkRow_ChkChanged" AutoPostback="true" />
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:Repeater>
```

And in my .cs page,

```
   protected void ChkRow_ChkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //some method
}
```

Comment: What was set as a trigger for your update panel & UpdateMode? Please add your code

Comment: Update mode is set to default and I have no triggers for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep your repeater inside update panel rather than entire page, if you want some other controls also need partial postback then you can go for multiple update panels.

Comment: Tried it,Kept the repeater inside update panel but still postback occurs.

Comment: I used both, keeping entire page in updatepanel and keeping only repeater. both worked, I am unable to generate your problem on my PC

Comment: In which panel should I change the Update Mode?

Comment: Yea I am using more than one update panel,I have other controls out of the repeater that post backs, that's the reason i have a update panel,from top to bottom.

Comment: Use only one, top to bottom and change update mode. You cant nest Update Panel inside other, got it?

Comment: Yea,I think the problem was with the browser,I now checked in Firefox it works,but in chrome it postbacks,could you too check it??

Comment: go through http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2011/11/update-panel-not-working-in-google.html